# How to set a different toolbar and hide previous toolbar in fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-toolbar

I am trying to inflate different toolbars in my fragments. Although I am able to inflate different toolbars for different fragments the problem is with MainActivity toolbar i am unable to hide it I have used

```
 (activity as AppCompatActivity).supportActionBar?.hide()
```

but it only hides the fragment toolbar, not the MainActivity toolbar I Want to hide the MainActivity toolbar.

My code

fragment

```
class SearchFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search, container, false)
        val toolbar = view.findViewById<Toolbar>(R.id.toolbar_search)

        (activity as AppCompatActivity).setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
        setHasOptionsMenu(true)
//        (activity as AppCompatActivity).supportActionBar?.hide()

        return view

    }
```

> Xml

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="56dp"
            app:titleTextColor="#000000"
            app:title="MainActivity"
            app:elevation="8dp" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
    
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Call hide method before calling `setSupportActionBar()`

Comment: What does it mean *"..but it only hides the fragment toolbar, not the MainActivity toolbar.."*. Do you have 2 toolbars in the same screen?

Comment: I have a bottom navigation bar in MainActivity so whenever I click on an item from the bottom navigation bar I want to inflate a different fragment and with each fragment a different toolbar. Yes I have 2 toolbars on in MainActivity layout file and one in fragment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the toolbar of the fragment is the one that hid because you add it on the activity and then you hide it so try to hide before adding the toolbar of the fragment

```
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search, container, false)
        val toolbar = view.findViewById<Toolbar>(R.id.toolbar_search)
        (activity as   AppCompatActivity).supportActionBar?.hide()
        (activity as AppCompatActivity).setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
        setHasOptionsMenu(true)
```